# How do I get the paymentMethodNonce

Tags: braintree

This is my code:

```
      <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
      <script>
          <?php $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate(array("customerId" => $aCustomerId)); ?>
      braintree.setup('<?php echo $clientToken; ?>', "dropin", {
        container: "dropin"

    });

      </script>
```

My question is how do I pass the paymentMethodNonce to my checkout page? Even with out the paymentMethodNonce, the sales are reflecting my Braintree sandbox. So my question is how do send the paymentMethodNonce to my checkout page.

Comment: I work at Braintree. I don't really understand your question. Your best bet is to [contact Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) with as much information as possible.